# How to navigate to a specific flutter route from an Android activity?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an existing android application and i have integrated flutter in my project i want to call a flutter specific route which i define in my main method like this

```
class FlutterView extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Platform View',
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
    '/secound': (context) => MyCustomForm(),
    '/dashboard': (context) => DashBoardScreen(),
    '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
  },
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
    textSelectionColor: Colors.red,
    textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

from my android activity i am calling flutter activity like this

startActivity(new Intent(this,FlutterActivity.class));

it does open my flutter activity but with the initialRoute: '/' which is fine but some time i want to open for eg( '/dashboard')  routes when i open a flutter activity how can i do it ??

Answer (score 9):

From Android, as stated [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20234#issuecomment-416928802):

```dart
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
intent.putExtra("route", "/routeName");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

From Flutter, using [`android_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent):

```dart
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'android.intent.action.RUN',

  // Replace this by your package name.
  package: 'app.example', 

  // Replace this by your package name followed by the activity you want to open.
  // The default activity provided by Flutter is MainActivity, but you can check
  // this in AndroidManifest.xml.
  componentName: 'app.example.MainActivity', 

  // Replace "routeName" by the route you want to open. Don't forget the "/".
  arguments: {'route': '/routeName'},
);

await intent.launch();
```

Notice that the app is going to open in this route only if it's terminated, that is, in case the app is in foreground or background, it won't open in the specified route.

Comment: great detailed answer, Thanks

Comment: It's work well, thanks so much

Comment: Hi, It is working fine. But sometimes it displays a blank page and the app will be crashed. Do you have any solution for that? Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: never seen anything like that. have you tested in different apps and different devices? i'd expect something like this to be a bug in a specific env.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method channel and call a flutter function from Android. In that function navigate your app from flutter to where ever you want.

for more info about how to use method channels to communicate between flutter and native code and vice versa. Please have a look

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: They have an example to send from dart to native. Not reverse direction example.

Comment: @Alexufo Here is a good tutorial as well  https://stablekernel.com/article/flutter-platform-channels-quick-start/

Comment: his code outdated but it is the way to looking for new code examples on github thanks

Comment: Can FlutterEngine 's NaviationChannel play any role in navigating? I've tried pushing and popping routes, it doesn't seem to be working.
see: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/systemchannels/NavigationChannel.html