# Is there a way to launch a specific flutter route directly from Android homescreen Widget?

Tags: android, flutter, android-widget

Sorry if there is anything wrong with the terminology I use. I would try to be as specific as possible and add extra info in brackets if i am not sure about the technical term.

I am creating an application for android just out of a hobby. I have written the application using flutter. and it has several screens(routes).
I want to add Android Homescreen widgets to launch each of these routes directly.

Example:

```
Flutter app
Routes:
         '/': (context) => MyApp(),
      '/audio': (context) => RecordAudio(),
    '/pictures': (context) => Pictures(),
```

I want to launch a specific route (like pictures) directly when I click on home screen widget.

I have added some code to create widgets in android, the code below will launch route "/"

```
        Intent mintent2;
        PendingIntent mpendIntent2;

        mintent2 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        mintent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mintent2.setData(Uri.parse(mintent2.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        mpendIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mintent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // }

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget_AudioButton, mpendIntent2);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds,views);
```

I have found few question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689327/how-to-navigate-to-a-specific-flutter-route-from-an-android-activity) where intent is used to launch route from activity, but i cannot find any reference where pendingintent is used.

let me know if you need any info. or anything I need to look into.
Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to directly add `intent.putExtra("route", "/routeName");` to your pending intent and following the link shared above, you should be able to get the desired behaviour. FYI, pendingIntent is like an intent but it has your app's context even if other app is handling the component.

Comment: like mintent2.putExtra("route", "/routeName");

Comment: Did it work? I am struck in similar situation.

Comment: yes @user3698694 it did work